# How to fetchAllBySql with a WHERE IN clause using Yii@1.1?

Tags: php, sql, yii, where-in, yii1.x

A legacy project uses yii@1.1. I want to create a query inside a `CActiveRecord`.

The query in raw sql would be:

```sql
SELECT column
FROM table
WHERE some_id in (1, 32, 10)
```

and it works fine when I query the DB directly. I get all the results.

I map that in my active record (`class MyActiveRecord extends CActiveRecord`) via following method in yii:

```php
    public function getColumn(array $someIds): array
    {
        $idList = rtrim(implode(', ', $someIds), ', ');
        $sql    = "SELECT column FROM table WHERE some_id IN (:idList)";

        $results = parent::model(__CLASS__)->findAllBySql(
            $sql,
            ['idList' => $idList]
        );

        return array_column($results, 'column');
    }
```

The code works but it strangely only fetches the result of the first `some_id`. How do I fetch all of them?

Say that my for my id 1 I have 5 results, for 32 I have 3, and for 10 I have 2 results, I expect a total of 10 records.

Yet I only get back the 5 results for the id 1 within yii. What am I doing wrong?

(When I changed the order of the id, always only the first id will be fetched, the others ignored.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will create query like `SELECT column FROM table WHERE some_id IN ('1, 32, 10')` - you're using one param and it is passed to query as one string value. To pass each ID independently, you must use multiple params:

```
$results = parent::model(__CLASS__)->findAllBySql(
   'SELECT column FROM table WHERE some_id IN (:id1, :id2, :id3)',
    ['id1' => 1, 'id2' => 32, 'id3' => 10]
);
```

Or avoid using params and use concatenation/interpolation, but **you need to sanitize/quote values first, to ensure that there is no SQL Injection risk**:

```
$ids = implode(', ', array_map('intval', $someIds);
$results = parent::model(__CLASS__)->findAllBySql(
   "SELECT column FROM table WHERE some_id IN ($ids)"
);
```

But probably the most safe and convenient option is to use [`CDbCommand`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand) to build your query:

```
$result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('column')
    ->from('table')
    ->where(['IN', 'id', $ids])
    ->queryColumn();
```

Answer (score 0):

I consider this a workaround but not a solution. I changed my code to use a CDbCriteria, yet I find it suboptimal as it will fetch all the fields. At least it yields my expected results:

```
$c = new CDbCriteria();
$c->compare('some_id', $someIds);
$result = $this->findAll($c);

return array_column($result, 'column');
```